# Apple Script, using mostly terminal commands, to get macbook in 'Perform Mode' Almost working, some commands aren't functioning

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, automation, applescript

I am using my personal macbook to perform live gigs with my band and to avoid it from malfunctioning or having trouble live I created an applescript I run before a gig that puts my macbook in 'Perform Mode'. In this mode everything is set to be CPU efficient and not mess with the performance. For example exposé and widgets are disabled, the background image is a solid colour, the output volume is muted (because all the output sound goes through an audio interface) and the backlight is set to a certain level.

I still have a few things that are not working though.
I know it is possible to 'mute' the keyboard backlight so it's off and can't be changed, but the

```
do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Keyboard Muted\" 1" password myPass with administrator privileges
```

line doesn't work.
Also the lines

```
do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 1\" 1.345887" password myPass with administrator privileges
```

and

```
do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 2\" 2.172732" password myPass with administrator privileges
```

won't work to set the backlight to a certain level.

The line

```
do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Automatic Display Enabled\" 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
```

doesn't work to disable the automatic light sensor.

And lastly the line

```
do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleInterfaceTheme Dark" password myPass with administrator privileges
```

doesn't work to set the theme to dark mode.

If you know what terminal command should be used instead of any of these lines please let me know.

Below is the full code:

```
set myPass to do shell script "security find-generic-password -wl \"ApplescriptPW\""

try
    do shell script "mkdir -p ~/Music/VarFiles/Desktop; touch ~/Music/VarFiles/varFilePerformMode.txt"
end try
if readVarPerformMode() is not "yes" then
    try
        set outputVolumeStatus to (output volume of (get volume settings))
    end try
    try
        set outputMutedStatus to (output muted of (get volume settings))
    end try
    try
        set alertVolumeStatus to (alert volume of (get volume settings))
    end try
    try
        set inputVolumeStatus to (input volume of (get volume settings))
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & outputVolumeStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileOutputVolume.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & outputMutedStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileOutputMuted.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & alertVolumeStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAlertVolume.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & inputVolumeStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileInputVolume.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "mv ~/Desktop/* ~/Music/VarFiles/Desktop"
    end try
    try
        set ambientLightSensorStatus to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Automatic Display Enabled\""
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & ambientLightSensorStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAmbientLightSensor.txt"
    end try
    try
        set keyboardMutedStatus to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Keyboard Muted\""
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & keyboardMutedStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileKeyboardMuted.txt"
    end try
    try
        set backlight1Status to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 1\""
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & backlight1Status & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBacklight1.txt"
    end try
    try
        set backlight2Status to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 2\""
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & backlight2Status & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBacklight2.txt"
    end try
    try
        set bluetoothStatus to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ControllerPowerState"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & bluetoothStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBluetooth.txt"
    end try
    try
        set infraredStatus to do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleIRController DeviceEnabled"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & infraredStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileInfrared.txt"
    end try
    try
        set spacesExposeStatus to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & spacesExposeStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileSpacesExpose.txt"
    end try
    try
        set dashboardStatus to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & dashboardStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileDashboard.txt"
    end try
    try
        set screensaverStatus to do shell script "defaults -currentHost  read com.apple.screensaver idleTime"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & screensaverStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileScreensaver.txt"
    end try
    try
        set pmsetStatus to do shell script "pmset -g custom"
        set fileContents to paragraphs of pmsetStatus
        if the first word of item 10 of fileContents is "displaysleep" then set batteryDisplaySleep to the last word of item 10 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 11 of fileContents is "sleep" then set batterySleep to the last word of item 11 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 15 of fileContents is "lessbright" then set batteryLessBright to the last word of item 15 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 16 of fileContents is "disksleep" then set batteryDiskSleep to the last word of item 16 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 26 of fileContents is "womp" then set acWomp to the the last word of item 26 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 27 of fileContents is "displaysleep" then set acDisplaySleep to the last word of item 27 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 29 of fileContents is "sleep" then set acSleep to the last word of item 29 of fileContents
        if the first word of item 33 of fileContents is "disksleep" then set acDiskSleep to the last word of item 33 of fileContents
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & batteryDisplaySleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBatteryDisplaySleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & batterySleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBatterySleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & batteryLessBright & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBatteryLessBright.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & batteryDiskSleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileBatteryDiskSleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & acWomp & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAcWomp.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & acDisplaySleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAcDisplaySleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & acSleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAcSleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & acDiskSleep & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileAcDiskSleep.txt"
    end try
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set desktopStatus to POSIX path of (get desktop picture as alias)
    end try
    try
        do shell script "echo " & desktopStatus & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFileDesktop.txt"
    end try
end if
try
    writeVarPerformMode("yes")
end try
try
    set volume output volume 0 with output muted
    set volume alert volume 0
    set volume input volume 0
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Automatic Display Enabled\" 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Keyboard Muted\" 1" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 1\" 1.345887" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.iokit.AmbientLightSensor \"Backlight 2\" 2.172732" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleIRController DeviceEnabled 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled 1"
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dashboard mcx-disabled 1"
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime 0"
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -a displaysleep 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -a sleep 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -b lessbright 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -c womp 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -a disksleep 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    tell application "Finder" to set desktop picture to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Pro Ultra Dark.png"
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleInterfaceTheme Dark" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true"
end try
try
    do shell script "scselect AirplaneMode"
end try
try
    do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled 0"
end try
try
    do shell script "mdutil -a -i off" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "tmutil disable" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui KeepAlive 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try
try
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem 1"
end try
try
    do shell script "pmset -a sms 0" password myPass with administrator privileges
end try

on writeVarPerformMode(theVar)
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (theVar as text) & " > ~/Music/VarFiles/varFilePerformMode.txt"
end writeVarPerformMode

on readVarPerformMode()
    try
        do shell script "cat ~/Music/VarFiles/varFilePerformMode.txt"
    end try
end readVarPerformMode
```